# Program supposed to display whole image only displaying part of it

Tags: java, image, swing, java-2d

```
public class Main extends JPanel{
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        static BufferedImage image;
        private static JPanel imagePanel;
        private static JFrame frame;

        private static String dir = "image\\pic.jpg";

        public Main(){
                try{
                        image = ImageIO.read(new File(dir));
                }catch (IOException e){
                        // If it cannot read from the directory inform the client
                        System.out.println("Error reading from directory: " + e.getMessage());
                }
        }
        //We set our preffered size if we succeed in loading the image
        public Dimension getPrefferedSize(){
                if(image == null){
                        return new Dimension(100, 100);
                }else{
                        return new Dimension(image.getWidth(null), image.getHeight(null));
                }
        }
        //Draw our image on the screen with Graphic's "drawImage()" method
        public void paint(Graphics g){
                g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
        }

        public static void main(String[] args){
                frame = new JFrame("Loading image from file example");
                imagePanel = new JPanel();
                //Release the resource window handle as we close the frame
                frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter(){
                                public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e){
                                        System.exit(0);
                                }
                        });
                try{
                        image = ImageIO.read(new File(dir));
                        if(image.getWidth(null) != 0){
                                System.out.println(image.getWidth(null));
                                System.out.println(image.getHeight(null));
                        }
                }catch(Exception e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                }
                imagePanel.add(new Main());
                frame.add(imagePanel);
                //frame.pack();
                frame.setSize(200, 300);
                frame.setVisible(true);
        }
        /*
        public static BufferedImage enlarge(BufferedImage image, int n){
                int w = n * image.getWidth();
                int h = n * image.getHeight();

                BufferedImage enlargedImage = new BufferedImage(w, h, image.getType());
                for (int y=0;y<h;y++){
                        for(int x=0;x<w;x++){
                                enlargedImage.setRGB(x, y, image.getRGB(x/n,  y/n));
                        }
                }

                return enlargedImage;
        }*/
}
```

I'm only getting the top-left 8x8 pixels of the image I provided ("pic.jpg").
Could anyone explain this?

Comment: Please post your pertinent code here, not in pastebin. You can click on the help button in the site's editor to learn how to format your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look over this code that corrects a variety of mistakes.  Most of the changes have comments.  Otherwise, check the docs. for the alternate methods.

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Main extends JPanel{

    static BufferedImage image;
    private static JPanel imagePanel;
    private static JFrame frame;

    private static String dir = "image\\pic.jpg";

    public Main(){
        image = new BufferedImage(400,140,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    }

    //We set our preffered size if we succeed in loading the image
    @Override  // TO DETECT WRONG SPELLING!
    public Dimension getPreferredSize(){
    /*
    public Dimension getPrefferedSize(){
    */
        if(image == null){
            return new Dimension(100, 100);
        }else{
            // A JPanel is an ImageObserver
            return new Dimension(image.getWidth(this), image.getHeight(this));
        }
    }

    //Draw our image on the screen with Graphic's "drawImage()" method
    // For Swing components.
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    // public void paint(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        // A JPanel is an ImageObserver
        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        frame = new JFrame("Loading image from file example");
        imagePanel = new JPanel();
        //Release the resource window handle as we close the frame
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        /*frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter(){
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e){
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });*/
        imagePanel.add(new Main());
        frame.add(imagePanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a layout manager that uses the full area of the `JPanel` rather than the default `FlowLayout`, which only uses the components preferred size. You can use

```
imagePanel.setLayout(new GridLayout());
```

Also override `paintComponent` instead of `paint` when doing custom painting in Swing and remember to invoke `super.paintComponent(g)`